# What's the meaning of the てですね ending?

Tags: word-choice, conjugations, て-form, politeness

I was reading a manga and a character who is really excited about the situation says "毎日何度も指折り数えてですね！". Why does it end with the て form and why is ですね added?

The full conversation is:

> A: 親から無事オッケーもらえて良かったねー
> B: はい！
> B: 私　ほんと　今日が楽しみで楽しみで
> B: 毎日何度も指折り数えてですね！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is functionally same as this one: [What exactly is this でね construction?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11950/7810)

> で is usually used to connect to phrases, but when the speaker is too excited about the first part already, s/he wants to affirm it with ね.

Except that:

- verb's te-form is used here, which is equivalent to noun/na-adj. + で (duh)
- has です in the middle

The seemingly dislocated です is put there to keep politeness (in order to talk to a senpai) which otherwise nowhere to place in this (half-)sentence. Generally, where final particles can be used, it can be buffed with です for politeness even no copula is expected.

> 俺**ね**、昨日ホームセンターで**ね**、こんな道具見つけたんだよ
>
> 私**ですね**、昨日ホームセンターで**ですね**、こんな道具見つけたんですよ

This is a colloquial grammar, because use of final particles as such is.