# Understanding もんでね

Tags: grammar

> 「……捕らえた者には賞金一〇〇万ドルだそうよ」
>
> 「ひゃあ、真那もとうとう賞金首でいやがりますか。————で、捕まえてみます？」
>
> 真那が言う通と、燎子はフンと鼻を鳴らした。
>
> 「あいにく、私はできるだけ部下と装備の損害を少なくすることも仕事**なもんでね**」

I’m not sure about the function of the bold part. Is the もんでね the continuative form of もんだね (which has the nuance of “that's the way it is" or 当然), as explained in this [thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11950/what-exactly-is-this-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AD-construction)?

Or does this もんでね mean “because”, like ものだから/ものですから?

Answer (score 2):

なもの suggests that one is describing something that's true and can't be changed (e.g. 太陽ってのは明るいものだ、親というのはそういうものだ).

Here, これも仕事なものだから means "this is part of my job (and I can't change that) - therefore". It's used as an "excuse", as in "I may or may not be finding it unfortunate, but regardless it's like this and I can't change it. So I'll have to act this way".

Other examples include: そういう性格なもんでね、そういう決まりなもんでね etc

Comment: Thank you. So generally, 「名詞+な+もんで」(at the end of a sentence) equals 「名詞+な+ものだから」, but doesn’t have the meaning of “because”?