# でね usage after a verb

Tags: particles

The following phrase is said in the beginning of the movie *Kimi no Na wa*:

> 明日{あした}はわたしが[作]{つく}るでね。

The characters are talking while eating breakfast, so the meaning is probably "I'll make breakfast tomorrow".

But what exactly is the function of `でね` in this sentence? At first I thought it was a combination of the contextual particle `で` and the sentence-ending particle `ね`, but how can "making breakfast" be a context? I must be getting something wrong.

Also, I don't think [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11950/what-exactly-is-this-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AD-construction) is related to the answer, since `でね` is coming after a non-conjugated verb here.

Comment: I'm not going to make it a full answer on the off chance that a native would have more to say about this, but this is basically 関西弁 way of saying よね, as far as I'm aware

Comment: @keke This is not 関西弁 but some other dialect. The meaning is close to 作るからね.

Comment: I don't know if it helps to identify the dialect or not, but the movie also uses や in place of だ more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This でね is roughly the same as sentence-end よ or からね in standard Japanese. This type of でね is not used in western dialects I'm familiar with. I don't know much about the areas where でね is used, but since the movie is set at a rural area in Gifu prefecture (middle Japan), it should be used at least in Gifu.

で that comes after the dictionary form of a predicate is a dialectal sentence-end particle similar to ぞ or よ. This particle itself is common also in Kansai-ben (eg 行くで, 作ったで, 嬉しいで, 本当やで), but it's usually not followed by ね in Kansai.

Comment: What kind から used in からね? Is it the same から used in warnings like「首にするからな!!」?

Comment: @JimmyYang Yes, that から that is similar in purpose to "You know", "Listen", "Keep in mind", etc.