# What does でね mean at the end of a sentence?

Tags: meaning, usage

I keep seeing this at the end of sentences lately, but couldn't find much explaining it online.  When I see it, I feel like it's usually serving as some kind of explanation but I'm not entirely sure.
For example, I was watching a show and a character asks why the other is wearing a uniform.  They then say:
今日バスケ部の試合だったんだ。ちょっとお手伝いでね。
I understand that he was explaining he was just there to help out, but I don't understand the nuance でね adds to the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

This is not some special construction, but is a simple combination of で and ね. ね is a sentence-final particle used to seek agreement or draw the listener's attention.

で can be either a case particle or the continuative form of the copula だ. As a case particle, で has many roles, so its translation can vary.

- 東京でね。
  (That is) in Tokyo, you know.
- 3日でね。
  Within three days, okay?
- ハサミでね。
  With/Using scissors, right?
- 1人でね!
  (You do it) alone!

Likewise, で in お手伝いで is a case particle that marks a condition/scope/situation.

- 手伝い**で**バスケの試合に出た。
  I went to a basketball game as an aid/help.
- ちょっとお手伝い**で**ね。
  As a little help, you know.

で can also be the te-form of the copula (だ). A te-form can be at the end of a sentence in casual speech. For examples of this type of でね, see: [What exactly is this でね construction?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11950/5010)