# What does くて mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntax

For what I have studied till know, くて is
1- the te-form for negative verbs or i-adjectives and it's used to conect the verb or adjective to another word.
2- at the end of a sentence, in the case of the て form, is the short version of てください. So I guess it could be that, but I could be horribly wrong about this.

いや。わたしというか父親が警察らしくてさ

Comment: [Kind of related](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11950/what-exactly-is-this-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ad-construction)

Comment: くて is not one word. 警察+らしい+て+さあ .